# How to use custom HandlerWrapper for Monolog in Symfony config.yml?

Tags: php, symfony, monolog

I would like to create a custom `HandlerWrapper` to use it with `Monolog` in my `Symfony 2.8` project.

**The goal is to use this `CustomHandler` as a filter that decides wether the wrapped/nested handler is called or not.**

==============

**UPDATE:** The following question is already solved thanks to the answer of @Yonel. However this brought ab a new problem described below.

Extending `Monolog\Handler\HandlerWrapper` is no problem of course. But I am struggling to us the custom class in the Monolog config within `config_prod.yml`:

```
namespace AppBundle\Log;

use Monolog\Handler\HandlerWrapper;

class CustomHandler extends HandlerWrapper {
    public function handle(array $record) {
        // some custom handling/processing...

        if ($this->doSomeCheck())
            return $this->handler->handle($record);
        else
            return false; // Do not call nested handler
    }
}
```

Config:

```
services:
    monolog.custom_handler.service:
        class: AppBundle\Log\CustomHandler

monolog:
    main:
        type: service
        id: monolog.custom_handler.service            
        level: error 
        handler: someHandler
    someHandler:
        ...
```

**Problem:** When running `app/console cache:warmup` on this config, I get the following error:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
>   Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Monolog\Handler\GroupHandler::__construct() must be of the type array,
>   none given

Well, I think the source of the problem is obvious: The service definition of `monolog.custom_handler.service` does not pass any argument to the class. But how can I pass `someHandler` as argument, as defined in the Monolog config?

==============

**EDIT: New Problem**

As Yonel describes in his answer, on can use the following config to pass `someHandler` to `custom_handler`:

```
services:
    monolog.custom_handler.service:
        class: AppBundle\Log\CustomHandler
        arguments:
            - '@monolog.handler.testHandler'

    monolog.test_handler.service:
        class: AppBundle\Log\TestHandler

monolog:
    # Skip level checking (can be solved by adding a FingersCrossed handler)
    main:
        type: service
        id: monolog.custom_handler.service   
    testHandler:
        type: service
        id: monolog.test_handler.service  
        nested: true
```

This works: `TestHandler` is now correctly passed to `CustomHandler`

However the goal was to let `CustomHandler` decide, wether `TestHandler` is called or not. This does not work with this config: `TestHandler` is called anyway (I assume directly by Monolog, as any other handler). It does not make any difference if `TestHandler` is passed to `CustomHandler`, marked as `nested` or not.

I implemented `CustomHandler` as `HandlerWrapper` and `TestHandler` as `AbstractHandler`. Both classes directly to a log file (not using Monolog) when their `handle` method is called. This way I can check if the handlers work as expected (`TestHandler` should only be called if `CustomHandler` allows it). **This is not the case.**

No matter if `TestHandler` is passed to `CustomHandler`, if it is marked as `nested`, if `CustomHandler` returns true or false in its `handle` method, etc., the result is always the same: `TestHandler` is called, no matter what `CustomHandler` decides.

**How to solve this?**

---

Handler implementations:

```
namespace AppBundle\Log;

use Monolog\Handler\HandlerWrapper;

class CustomHandler extends HandlerWrapper {
    public function handle(array $record) {
        // some custom handling/processing...

        if ($this->doSomeCheck()) {
            $this->directlyWriteToFileNotUsingMonolog('CustomHandler: Call TestHandler');  
            return $this->handler->handle($record);
        else {

            $this->directlyWriteToFileNotUsingMonolog('CustomHandler: Do NOT call TestHandler');  
            return false; // Do not call nested handler
        }
    }


class TestHandler extends AbstractHandler {
    public function handle(array $record) {
        $this->directlyWriteToFileNotUsingMonolog('TestHandler');  
        return false; 
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of asking a new question in this one, create another question, and validate Yonel's answer please.

Comment: I considered this, but the original question/problem is still the same. So I decided to update the question instead. But maybe you are right an a new question is the better option

Comment: Where is the "answer of @Yonel"? Is this making a reference to another question??