# How to do advanced filtering of Monolog messages in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, monolog

I am using the `MonologBundle` in my `Symfony 2.8` project to manage log messages. Using different `Handlers` it is no problem to write logs to file and to send them by e-mail at the same time.

I would like to reduce the number of messages I receive by mail. I already use the `DeduplicationHandler` and the `FingersCrossed` handler to filter by error level and to avoid duplicate messages. This works fine but is not enough.

For example I would like to reduce the number of mail about `PageNotFound` errors. Of course I want to be notified if `/existingPage` is not found, but I am not interested in messages about `/.well-known/...` files.

Another example are messages about errors in a third party CSV parser component. There are several known and harmless errors I am not interested in, but of course other errors are important.

This these errors/messages are generated by third party code, I cannot influence the source. I could only ignore these messages completely but this is not what I want.

**I am looking for a solution to filter the messages by content. How can this be done in Monolog?**

I already tried to solve this using a `HandlerWrapper` and discussed this issue in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40218472): The idea was, that the `HandlerWrapper` acts as filter. The `HandlerWrapper` is called by Monolog, it checks the message content and decides wether it should be processed or not (e.g. discard all messages including the text "./well-known/"). If a messages passes, the `HandlerWrapper` should simple hand it over to its nested/wrapped handler. Otherwise the message is skipped without further processing.

However this idea did not work, and the answers to the other question indicate, that a `HandlerWrapper` is not the right approach for this problem.

So the new/actual question is: **How to create a filter for Monolog messages, that let me control wether a specific message should be process or not?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure why using a HandlerWrapper is the wrong way to do it.

I had the same issue and figured a way how to wrap a handler in order to filter certain records.

In this answer I describe two ways to solve this, a more complex and an easy one.

#### (More or less) complex way

First thing I did, was to create a new class wich extends the HandlerWrapper and added some logic where I can filter records:

```php
use Monolog\Handler\HandlerWrapper;

class CustomHandler extends HandlerWrapper
{
    public function isHandling(array $record)
    {
        if ($this->shouldFilter($record)) {
            return false;
        }

        return $this->handler->isHandling($record);
    }

    public function handle(array $record)
    {
        if (!$this->isHandling($record)) {
            return false;
        }

        return $this->handler->handle($record);
    }

    public function handleBatch(array $records)
    {
        foreach ($records as $record) {
            $this->handle($record);
        }
    }

    private function shouldFilter(array $record)
    {
        return mt_rand(0, 1) === 1;; // add logic here
    }
}
```

Then I created a service definition and a CompilerPass where I can wrap the GroupHandler

`services.yml`

```
CustomHandler:
    class: CustomHandler
    abstract: true
    arguments: ['']
```

```php
use Monolog\Handler\GroupHandler;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ChildDefinition;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;

class CustomMonologHandlerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        if (!$container->hasDefinition(CustomHandler::class)) {
            return;
        }

        $definitions = $container->getDefinitions();
        foreach ($definitions as $serviceId => $definition) {
            if (!$this->isValidDefinition($definition)) {
                continue;
            }

            $cacheId = $serviceId . '.wrapper';

            $container
                ->setDefinition($cacheId, new ChildDefinition(CustomHandler::class))
                ->replaceArgument(0, new Reference($cacheId . '.inner'))
                ->setDecoratedService($serviceId);
        }
    }

    private function isValidDefinition(Definition $definition): bool
    {
        return GroupHandler::class === $definition->getClass();
    }
}
```

As you can see I go over all definitions here and find the ones which have the GroupHandler set as their class. If this is the case, I add a new definition to the container which decorates the original handler with my CustomHandler.

**Side note**: *At first I tried to wrap all handlers (except the CustomHandler of course :)) but due to some handlers implementing other interfaces (like the [ConsoleHandler](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/77639e2564348deef06cdda9b681d7583146c315/src/Symfony/Bridge/Monolog/Handler/ConsoleHandler.php) using the EventSubscriberInterface) this did not work and lead to issues I didn't want to solve in some hacky way.*

Don't forget to add this compiler pass to the container in your AppBundle class

```
class AppBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $container->addCompilerPass(new CustomMonologHandlerPass());
    }
}
```

Now that everything is in place you have to group your handlers in order to make this work:

`app/config(_prod|_dev).yml`

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        my_group:
            type: group
            members: [ 'graylog' ]
        graylog:
            type: gelf
            publisher:
                id: my.publisher
            level: debug
            formatter: my.formatter
```

#### Easy way

We use the same CustomHandler as we did in the complex way, then we define our handlers in the config:

`app/config(_prod|_dev).yml`

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        graylog:
            type: gelf
            publisher:
                id: my.publisher
            level: debug
            formatter: my.formatter
```

Decorate the handler in your services.yml with your own CustomHandler

`services.yml`

```
CustomHandler:
    class: CustomHandler
    decorates: monolog.handler.graylog
    arguments: ['@CustomHandler.inner']
```

For the *decorates* property you have to use the format `monolog.handler.$NAME_SPECIFIED_AS_KEY_IN_CONFIG`, in this case it was graylog.

... and thats it

#### Summary

While both ways work, I used the first one, as we have several symfony projects where I need this and decorating all handlers
manually is just not what I wanted.

I hope this helps (even though I'm quite late for an answer :))

Comment: I was able to make it work using the "easy way". I didn't really get how the "complex way" is supposed to work.

Answer (score 1):

In my humble opinion, there is a simpler and clean way (maybe it was not available when the first answer was done).

I write it here because I think it can help a lot of people who need to filter their logs with a simple answer, understanding what they do:

Just implements a simple handler from AbstractHandler :

```php
use Monolog\Handler\AbstractHandler;

/** Simple handler wrapper that filters records based on content. */
class FilterHandler extends AbstractHandler
{
    /** For Monolog 3+, typehint with LogRecord instead of array */
    public function isHandling(array $record): bool
    {
        // This function is called only with level info, so always return true if you don't want to filter on level (cf AbstractHandler phpdoc)
        return true;
    }

    /** Handles a record. Idem, for Monolog 3+, typehint with LogRecord */
    public function handle(array $record): bool
    {
        return $this->shouldFilter($record);
    }

    // Just a simple exemple (idem, Logrecord for Monolog 3+)
    private function shouldFilter(array $record): bool
    {
        return
            array_key_exists('context', $record) &&
            array_key_exists('route', $record['context']) &&
            'app_logout' === $record['context']['route']
        ;
    }
}
```

Then in `services.yaml`, declare your Handler (as ordinary service) :

```yaml
services:
    my_filter_handler:
        class: App\MyFilterNamespace\FilterHandler
        public: false
```

And in your `monolog.yaml` conf, just add your handler on the top of the handlers with the type `service`:

```yaml
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: service
            id: my_filter_handler
            handler: rotating        # next handler
        rotating:
            type: rotating_file      # or whatever you need
            [...]
```

Comment: worked flaweless!